# Inheriting from RKObjectManager when using RestKit

Tags: ios, ios7, restkit, restkit-0.20

In some tutorials (such as: http://restkit-tutorials.com/code-organization-in-restkit-based-app/) the recommendation is to inherit from RKObjectManager for each resource.
However, if i understand correctly, i should use the sharedInstance of RKObjectManager. It means that there should be only one such object manager.

What is the correct way to go? What are the risks of inheriting from RKObjectManager?

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to use the `sharedInstance` of `RKObjectManager`, it a convenience. How you approach the problem is a personal preference. I generally don't subclass, I use composition (so I instantiate an object manager of each endpoint / type of activity and configure it), but both ways work. In either case you just need to maintain multiple instances of object managers, either directly, or by instantiating your subclasses. You choose whether to have a class which creates and configures the manager(s), or to have each subclass perform the configuration and another class which just instantiates them all.

Generally it is easier to use multiple instances than to try to cram everything into a single instance (the `sharedInstance`). If you organise your instances up front rather than just trying to use `sharedInstance` it will set you up well for the future.